# como desabilitar ou habilitar input text através de um input radio reativo

Tags: angular, formulário, reactive-programming

Estou chamando desta forma no html

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4 center-zone">
    <input-radio id="controle" theme="boolean" label="tem controle?" (click)="valueSelect($event)"></input-radio>
  </div>

  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
    <msp-input-text id="tipo" [disabled]="true" label=" Qual o tipo de controle? "tooltip="ajustar"></msp-input-text>
  </div>
```

Os temas do campo radio Boolean são: SIM, NÃO, INDIFERENTE

Adicionei no formGroup desta forma

```
  controle: [null],

  tipo: [{ value: null, disabled: true }, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)]],
```

e montei está função ao selecionar o valor do radio

```
    valueSelect(event: any) {
    console.log(event)
    if (event.value) {
      this.form.controls['chassi'].enable();
    } else {
      this.form.controls['chassi'].disable();
    }
  }
```

Ao executar, ele abre desativado (ok, correto), ao clicar em **sim ele precisa habilitar** e caso **não ele desabilita**, porem não estou conseguindo fazer isso, podem me ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc pode fazer assim:

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4 center-zone">
    <input-radio formControl="controle" id="controle" theme="boolean" label="tem controle?" ></input-radio>
  </div>

  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
    <msp-input-text  formControl="tipo" id="tipo" [disabled]="!form.value.controle" label=" Qual o tipo de controle? "tooltip="ajustar"></msp-input-text>
  </div>
```